# Serial communication with Windows Phone 8

Tags: android, serial-port, windows-phone

Does windows phone 8 support serial communication?
I am working on my graduation project now. I plan to use a phone to communicate with a RFID　device via a serial port.

I get three solution.

1. Use Windows Mobile 6
2. Use Windows Phone 7 or 8
3. Use Android

Personally, I prefer 2. But I am not sure whether Windows Phone support serial communication or not. If not, is there any solution?

Comment: later I got using a android phone to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with windows phone 7, but with windows phone 8 you have access to the Bluetooth API so you could try serial over Bluetooth.

Comment: so except wp,any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

With Android, you can use serial communication over USB cable. It depends on your requirements but setting up a USB connection is sometimes easier than managing a bluetooth connection.

It is up to you.

Comment: Serial communication over USB requires either that the android device support the optional USB host mode (both electrically and in exposing the APIs) or that you have an external device which acts as a USB host to use the ADK, or failing that ADB, channels into the phone.